# ExpressJS route not working?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express with hoganjs templating instead of jade.

When I try to access one of my routes, it wont work though...

In app.js, I have the following (relevant to the route):

```
var awesome = require('./routes/awesome.js');
app.use('/awesome', awesome);
```

In the routes/awesome.js file, I have the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET awesome page. */
router.get('/awesome', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('awesome', { title: "awesome", message: "awesome"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

And lastly, here is my awesome template (located in ./views/awesome.hjs).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta name="Author" content="{{author}}"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
                <p>Welcome to {{ title }}, here is your message: {{message}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have basically the same code for the index route so why wont this one work too?

Comment: For those who may wonder, it throws a 404 since it thinks that the route doesnt exist, but as you can see, I have clearly defined my route, unless im just being blind...

Comment: According your current logic your route looks so: `/awesome/awesome`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awesome.js change the router path location to `/`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('awesome', { title: "awesome", message: "awesome"});
});
```

Now `localhost:3000/awesome` should be available.

`app.use('/awesome', ...)` matches all the routes starting with `awesome`. Paths specified in `router.get('/awesome', ...)` acts as sub-paths. The path URL will be `localhost:3000/awesome/awesome`.

Comment: That fixed it... what the hell though?! ahahha

Comment: I can accept the answer in 3 minutes it says :P Yeah I understand, but it seems kind of... you know... silly :P.

Comment: Cant believe that is what it was, I was reading my code over and over thinking wtf is happening.. haha